# jetty http2client start failed

Tags: http2, jetty-9

I use jetty http2client, and start failed:

```
    QueuedThreadPool clientThreadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
    clientThreadPool.setName("http2Client");
    clientThreadPool.setIdleTimeout(http2ClientIdletimeout);
    clientThreadPool.setMaxThreads(http2ClientMaxThread);
    clientThreadPool.setMinThreads(http2ClientMinThread);
    http2Client.setExecutor(clientThreadPool);
    http2Client.setInitialSessionRecvWindow(FlowControlStrategy.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);
    http2Client.setInitialStreamRecvWindow(FlowControlStrategy.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);
    sslContextFactory = sslContextHolder.buildJettySSLContextFactory();
    http2Client.addBean(sslContextFactory);
```

And the exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$$Lambda$7/352598575@436c81a3
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.execute(QueuedThreadPool.java:385) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.execute(SelectorManager.java:107) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.doStart(ManagedSelector.java:96) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:240) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client.doStart(HTTP2Client.java:166) ~[http2-client-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-runner-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
```

Anyone have ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't specify the Jetty version you are using. Your snippet of code works fine for me.

Comment: I use jetty-9.4.6.v20170531. [jetty github](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1913) gives me some ideas, trying now.